# Why can't I play preview my simple Unity Scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm new to using Unity so is likely a really easy fix. I have taken a 3D Google SketchUp model and I'm looking to have a player look around the model. Super simple.

I have added the 3D Plane, added the Camera and updated the setting to support VR. When I click the Play Preview Button I get the following error:

> Virtual Reality SDK Oculus failed to initialize. Will attempt to
>   enable OpenVR instead.
>
> XR: OpenVR Error! OpenVR failed initialization with error code
>   VRInitError_Init_PathRegistryNotFound: "Installation path could not be
>   located (110)"!

When I click on the play preview, I'm unable to move the camera around.

I have tried reinstalling Unity. The current version is 2019.3.0a3

I'm looking to be able to preview the scene and be able to move the camera
around. As if the game was being played in on an Oculus Headset.

Instead I'm getting:

> XR: OpenVR Error! OpenVR failed initialization with error code
>   VRInitError_Init_PathRegistryNotFound: "Installation path could not be
>   located (110)"!

Comment: This same / similar error occurs if the user does not have a headset plugged in. The message is coming from the OpenVR package.

Please be sure that Unity has the OpenVR package installed or the OpenVR SDK is not enabled in the Standalone player settings (presuming the application does not wish to target OpenVR / Steam)

Comment: Thank you, OpenVR was selected. That had been annoying me for ages! I'm just left with the warning message:

Virtual Reality SDK Oculus failed to initialize.
Will attempt to enable None instead.

I have a wireless headset connected to I need to edit the Unity properties to sort this? As the Play Preview still won't allow me to rotate the screen?

Comment: Also when I try to import Oculus Integration from the Asset Store, I get 60 different errors. https://ibb.co/hcKLQfK

Answer (score -1):

penVR Error! OpenVR failed initialization with error code VRInitError_Init_PathRegistryNotFound: "Installation path could not be located (110)"!'

i try
just remove OpenVR from PlayerSetting->Built Settings->Other Settings-> XR Settings-> Select Open VR and press "-" minus button

project is not showing in oculus rift but the error is gone